# Updating records that are exported using BCP utility

Tags: sql, sql-update, bcp

I am using the BCP utility to export data from SQL to flat file, and export is done in batches (using the -F and -L attributes). But I want to write an Update query to identify the exported records that will run just after the BCP (in the same Stored proc).

Since I am just passing only the first and last row numbers (not tale Id) to export data, how can I use this data to make the table update?

What I am looking for : **Update 'table' Where 'Row from..To'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get row numbers, but note that you have to specify an ordering for that, so your bcp will need to use the same ordering.

`ROW_NUMBER()` can't occur outside a SELECT or ORDER BY, so you will need a subquery or CTE

E.g.

```
bcp "select * from `table` order by ID" <other bcp params> -F @First -L @Last

WITH rows AS (
SELECT <columns to be updated>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) rn FROM `table`
)
UPDATE rows
SET <some indicator>
WHERE rn BETWEEN @First AND @Last
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6388/7)